# Calling Drupal URL from another server using php

Tags: php, drupal

I am trying to call drupal 6 URL from my local system, that URL will generate a xml file.
My system does not have drupal intallation. I tried file_get_content("www.abc.com") but it does not write my xml file but when I try to run the url normally it runs and xml file gets generated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use sockets or just file_get_contents, like

```
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/');
echo $homepage; // $homepage contains server response without headers
```

Comment: file_get_contents doesnt help, I want to execute the url from a local machine so that the xml is generated